# `Dart: Open Observatory` not opening in VS Code for Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, memory, dart-devtools

I want to observe the memory consumption of my Flutter Desktop app.

I noticed that the older version of the Dart Devtools has this Observatory homepage:
[image: Observatory Homepage]
I took this from YouTube - Flutter performance videos 1-3 years ago.

The problem is, when I search for `Dart: Open Observatory` in the VSCode, it doesn't open or do anything:
[image: Open Observatory]

When I run `flutter run -d macos`, both URLs below:

```
A Dart VM Service on macOS is available at: <URL>
The Flutter DevTools debugger and profiler on macOS is available at: <URL>
```

it opens to `Performance` tab by default:
[image: Performance tab]

And in the `Memory` tab:
[image]

Currently, it doesn't have these 2 anymore:

1. current memory
2. peak memory

Is this not available in the latest Dart Devtools anymore? Where can I find the `current memory` and `peak memory`?

Comment: if you end up [raising an issue ticket](https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/new?assignees=&labels=is+bug&projects=&template=bug_report.md&title=), please ping me with a link to it.

Comment: @starball i created a ticket [here](https://github.com/flutter/devtools/issues/6159)  instead, which is at `flutter/devtools` repo. should i create a new one under your link's (`Dart-Code/Dart-Code`) repo?

Comment: in that case no need to create another unless the maintainers ask you to.

Answer (score 3):

The maintainers of the flutter devtools discussed this in issue ticket https://github.com/flutter/devtools/issues/6159. According to Kenzie Davisson, "*the observatory has been deprecated in favor of Dart DevTools.*". Danny Tuppeny replied that the `Dart: Open Observatory` command is "*still possible to use [...] if you have an older SDK or have configured `--serve-observatory` in your `toolArgs` so it might be useful to have. Once we have an SDK version that removes `--serve-observatory` we could use that version number to hide it from new SDKs that definitely don't support it (and in the meantime we could add "(Deprecated)" to the end)*", then later: "*I've opened [Dart-Code/Dart-Code#4697](https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/4697) about marking it deprecated and [Dart-Code/Dart-Code#4696](https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/4696) about hiding it once we have an SDK version that does not include it.*"